# Worklight JSONStore initCollection Error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

envrionment:

- Worklight v5.0.5

When I used the character starts from `digit(ex. 0, 9)` or `_` as the collection name,
`PERSISTENT_STORE_FAILURE` error occurred.

code like below

```
var name = '0aaa';
WL.JSONStore.initCollection(name, searchfields, [options]);
```

Comment: Hmmm, will take a look. Is this on Android or iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start JSONStore collections with a letter [A-Z]+ or [a-z]+. For example: `aaa` instead of `0aaa`. I have opened a bug to look into allowing collections to start with number and symbols for future releases of JSONStore.

Comment: OK. It's bug... I will use letters instead of digits or symbols. thanks. waiting for future release..